# How to check whether a variable is declared in D?

Tags: d, introspection, conditional-compilation, compile-time-constant

How do I check whether a variable exists, i.e. is already declared in D?

The background is that I want to use version conditions but still have a default value:

```
version(A)
{
  immutable int var = 1;
}
version(B)
{
  immutable int var = 2;
}
// this is pseudo code
if (var is not yet declared)
{
  immutable int var = 3;
}
```

I just assume that this is possible in D as it has so much introspection...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, given what your use case appears to be, you're going about it incorrectly. You really should do something more like

```
version(A)
{
    immutable int var = 1;
}
else version(B)
{
    immutable int var = 2;
}
else
{
    immutable int var = 3;
}
```

But in the general case, if you're looking specifically to test whether a symbol exists, use `is(typeof(symbol))` where `symbol` is the name of the symbol that you're testing for. So, if you wanted to test whether the variable `var` existed, you would do something like

```
static if(is(typeof(var)))
{
    //var exists
}
```

and of course to test that it *doesn't* exist, you just negate the condition:

```
static if(!is(typeof(var)))
{
    //var does not exist
}
```

`typeof(exp)` gets the type of an expression, and if the expression is invalid (because of  a variable which doesn't exist or a function in the expression doesn't work with those arguments or whatever), then the result is `void`. `is(type)` checks whether the type is non-`void`. So, `is(typeof(exp))` tests whether exp is a valid expression, and in the case where it's just a symbol name, that means that it's testing whether it's a valid symbol or not.

Comment: The first one is what I needed. I did not know that `version` works with `if else` type syntax. Thanks for that solution. As of the second "solution": I tried with `typeof` but without the `is()` so I got a compiler error. I learned twice as much as I expected ;)